# python libraries managed by conda and native python

Tags: python, anaconda

In my Ubuntu 14.04 computer, I have installed two kinds of Python, one is called native python, which comes along with the Ubuntu operating system, and the other is the conda version, which is installed after I installed the conda package.

If I launch python command, the default python refers to the conda version.

Using conda can bring a lot of advantages for package management. But before I installed conda, I have already installed some Python modules with the native Python by using pip install command. These modules, however, are not reachable by conda Python. So, here is my question: how can I set conda so that it can use the packages managed by native python?

When I ask this question, I cannot help asking another questions:

- Is it a good practice to mix packages managed by conda and native python? Any practice I can follow?
- How can I switch Python to native Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good practice to mix packages managed by conda and native python. You can still, however, install Python modules using `pip` into Anaconda. I would recommend strictly using Anaconda (and use `conda` virtual environments as well as the `conda` package manager), and not using native python any longer.

Your best bet is to use strictly Anaconda moving forward. I would reinstall the packages into a conda virtual environment.

`conda create --name NAME_HERE`

or

`conda create --name NAME_HERE --clone root` if you want to include all packages that come with Anaconda by default.

Then switch to your new environment with `source activate NAME_HERE` (Linux, macOS) or `activate NAME_HERE` (Windows). Then you can install packages with both the `conda` package manager and `pip`.

See [the conda docs on managing conda virtual environments](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) for details.

Kind user @MikhailKnyazev has pointed out that this is how you *would* use the packages managed by native python. It is still **not recommended**.

> Although it is certainly not a good practice, it is useful to know
>   that you can add system-side packages inside virtual environment by
>   symlinking them like this: `ln -s /usr/lib/<PYTHON_VER>/dist-packages/<PACKAGE> <virtualenv_path>/lib/<PYTHON_VER>/site-packages/`

Comment: Although it is certainly not a good practice, it is useful to know that you can add system-side packages inside virtual environment by symlinking them like this: `ln -s /usr/lib/<PYTHON_VER>/dist-packages/<PACKAGE> <virtualenv_path>/lib/<PYTHON_VER>/site-packages/`

Comment: @MikhailKnyazev great point. Your comment actually addresses the question at hand.

Comment: considering switching to native python I bet in the very end of `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` there is a line like `export PATH="/home/<user>/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`. Remove it and you'll get system python back.